# Using BandpassFilter

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7G3oUuZG1TwRHNNV1RFZjFWUXM/view?usp=sharing

Above I have linked a data set containing a 2 seconds EEG sample I have recorded of someone "blinking". This data set was taken at a 220hz frequency. I am attempting to apply the function BandpassFilter[] function to isolate specific frequency bands in the EEG spectrum listed in the code.

```
data= Flatten@Import["C:\\Users\\YottaTech\\Desktop\\FacialData\\Duhe\\
John\\Blink\\1\\Blink.data.1.26.10.9.4.2167734.csv"];

(*These are the frequency band ranges (in Hz) I would like to filter out*)
delta = {.1, 3};
theta = {4, 7};
alpha = {8, 12};
beta = {12, 30};
gamma = {30,50};

(*Here is my initial attempt to filter out the ""Delta" frequency band*)
deltaFreq = BandpassFilter[data, {2*Pi*.1,2*Pi*3}];
```

Would anyone be able to show me where I am going wrong with this? Or show more a more powerful/efficient function to utilize to accomplish the task?

Comment: I saw this question before. Wasn't it migrated to Signal Processing?

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28965/filtering-frequency-bands-out-of-a-signal/28972?noredirect=1#comment54288_28972

Comment: I am more interested in high efficiency ways of designing functions and kernels to accomplish the goal though. I will have 100's of GB's of data to analyze in the near future and have 16GB right now.

Comment: See also related question here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42027/58

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative to using `BandpassFilter`, which may or may not be any better.

You can use `Fourier` to extract only a few components.

```
delta = {0.1,3}; (*in Hz*)
theta = {4, 7};
alpha = {8, 12};
beta = {12, 30};
gamma = {30, 50};
```

Take the elements you want, and create a filtered FFT, we're effectively creating a square bandpass filter. This will not handle frequencies above sample freq./2 without more care.

```
fftFilter[data_, sR_, band_] := Module[
  {dur, fRes, f1, f2, rSpan, f},
  dur = Length@data/sR;(*Total duration of data.*)
  fRes = 1/dur;(*Resolution of FFT is 1/duration.*)
  (*frequencies in terms of Fourier part.1=DC*)
  {f1, f2} = 1 + Quotient[#, fRes] & /@ band;

  rSpan = If[f1 == 1, Span @@ {2, -1}, Span @@ {1, -1}];
  f = Fourier[data, List /@ Range[f1, f2]];
  f = PadLeft[f, f2];
  f = Join[PadRight[f, (Length@data) - f2 + 1], 
    Conjugate@Reverse@(f[[rSpan]])];
  f = PadRight[f, Length@data];
  Re@InverseFourier[f]
  ]
```

I plot each of the bands separately and then combine all of the band information as a check. It seems to look ok.

```
ListPlot[
 MapIndexed[# + 400*(First@#2 - 1) &,
  # - Mean@# & /@ (MapIndexed[
     fftFilter[data, 220, #] &, {delta, theta, alpha, beta, gamma}
     ])
  ]
 , Joined -> True
 , PlotLegends -> LineLegend[
   ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range[5]
   ,
   {"delta", "theta", "alpha", "beta", "gamma"}
   ]
 , PlotLabel -> "Band Data"
 ]

ListPlot[
 {
  data,
  Total[
   fftFilter[data, 220, #] & /@ {delta, alpha, beta, gamma, theta}
   ]
  }
 , PlotLegends -> LineLegend[
   ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range[2]
   ,
   {"Data", "\[CapitalSigma] bands"}
   ]
 , Joined -> True
 , PlotRange -> All
 , PlotLabel -> "Sum of Bands"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: So is the difference between red and blue the 2 Pi I missed? It would make sense since the red curve has more high frequency noise cut out.

Comment: @JasonB, I changed the pictures.  The `BandpassFilter` solution isn't shown in these. But no, adding the factor of 2pi doesn't seem to reproduce what I've shown, it still shows more high frequency than seems reasonable to me.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it won't handle frequencies bellow sample frequency/2? Does this mean I can't filter frequencies bellow 110Hz?

Comment: Above sample frequency/2, not below. That's just the Nyquist limit. What I meant was if you ask the function I wrote for a frequency above that it's going to freak out because I didn't put any checks in.

Comment: Got cha, thanks.

Comment: Would you by chance have any tips for filtering out artifacts such as the 2 spikes we see caused from the blinking from the signal?

Answer (score 6):

If your sampling rate is 220 Hz, then you need to tell *Mathematica* that, otherwise the frequencies you are giving are meaningless.

```
deltaFreq = BandpassFilter[data, delta, SampleRate -> 220];

ListLinePlot /@ {data, deltaFreq}
```

[image]

Here you can see the result of successive action of the `BandpassFilter`

```
Manipulate[
 Fold[(BandpassFilter[#1, #2, SampleRate -> 220] &), 
   data, {{0, 10000}, delta, theta, alpha, beta, gamma}[[;; n]]] // 
  ListLinePlot, {{n, 1}, 1, 6, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: `delta` is given in Hz so you need to multiply it by 2Pi

Comment: @SimonWoods That makes sense, I'm away from the office so I can't fix it now but I did get the biggest mistake in the OP I think with the `SampleRate` option

Comment: I'm suspicious of the output of `BandpassFilter`, I feel like those peaks should be changing more significantly from band to band.

Comment: @N.J.Evans It might have been more interesting to apply the filters in the opposite order, or one at a time rather than cumulatively

Comment: @JasonB I missed the `Fold`. I think OP may have missed that as well, based on the labels he gave in his answer.

Comment: I just noticed the fold and what you guys are talking about and am editing my response.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Flatten@
Import["C:\\Users\\YottaTech\\Desktop\\FacialData\\Duhe \
William\\Blink\\1\\Blink.data.1.26.10.26.49.6077426.csv"];

labels = {"Delta", "Theta", "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "High"};
delta = 2*\[Pi]*{.1, 3};
theta = 2*\[Pi]*{4, 7};
alpha = 2*\[Pi]*{8, 12};
beta = 2*\[Pi]*{12, 30};
gamma = 2*\[Pi]*{30, 50};
high = 2*\[Pi]*{50, 80};

freqBands = {delta, theta, alpha, beta, gamma, high};

Manipulate[
Column[{
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> Full, PlotLabel -> "Raw"], 
ListLinePlot[
BandpassFilter[data, freqBands[[n]], SampleRate -> 220], 
PlotLabel -> labels[[n]], PlotRange -> Full]
}],
{{n, 1}, 1, Length[freqBands], 1}]
```

After reviewing all the help I have arrived at a correctly working bandpass filter approach! Thank you guys very much for the help and I have included the working code above for reference.